# NSDictionary - Check if object has any keys

Tags: objective-c, json, key, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am working with the Pocket API, it returns a JSON feed with my "read later" items. The key/value names are dynamic (they keep changing), so in order to parse through them, I am using `[object allKeys]` to get all the different keys. I then loop through that array and store all the data I need in my custom object.

The problem I am having is when the `list` object is empty (ie: when I am performing pagination). When it is empty, performing `[object allKeys]` crashes, because there are no keys in the dictionary.

Is there a way to check if an `NSDictionary` object, contains any keys or not?

Normal `list` object structure:

```
list = {

    1170784230 = {
        "amp_url" = "http://jalopnik.com/jaguar-f-type-svr-this-is-it-in-all-its-575-horsepower-1754489727/amp",
        "excerpt" = "A lot of things have run through my mind when I\U2019ve driven the Jaguar F-Type R. \U201cThis thing desperately needs more horsepower\U201d has never been one of them. But we are in the age of overkill, and our beloved F-Type is about to get a heavy dose of just that. Meet the insane F-Type SVR.",
        "favorite" = "true",
        "given_title" = "",
        "given_url" = "http://jalopnik.com/jaguar-f-type-svr-this-is-it-in-all-its-575-horsepower-1754489727",
        "has_image" = 1,
        "has_video" = 0
    };
};
```

Empty `list` object structure:

```
list = {
};
```

How can I detect if an object contains any keys without crashing?

### Update 1

Here is the crash log:

```
2017-10-05 10:37:37.864293+0100 TestApp[68108:5683371] -[__NSArray0 allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000000050
2017-10-05 10:37:37.867373+0100 TestApp[68108:5683371] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2017-10-05 10:37:37.867409+0100 TestApp[68108:5683371] [General] -[__NSArray0 allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000000050
2017-10-05 10:37:37.867506+0100 TestApp[68108:5683371] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f81a0fb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff56106c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f8b2c34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f790510 ___forwarding___ + 1456
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f78fed8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TestApp                           0x000000010006e5c4 __52-[DataManager loadPocketData:pagination:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 356
    6   TestApp                           0x0000000100041c52 __51-[DataManager loadNetworkCustomRequest:completion:]_block_invoke + 162
    7   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff2e7297bf __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
    8   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff2e729021 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 147
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff3185bab3 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff3185b915 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff31859dc2 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100432f1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100446a14 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 576
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100432f1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100446a14 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 576
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001004467b4 dispatch_block_perform + 109
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff31855dd0 __NSOQSchedule_f + 342
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100432f1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001004475be _dispatch_continuation_pop + 940
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010043e5af _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 738
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100434d77 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 723
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100434a50 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 116
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001004af1d2 _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001004aec55 start_wqthread + 13
)
2017-10-05 10:37:37.868416+0100 TestApp[68108:5683371] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArray0 allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000000050'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f81a0fb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff56106c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f8b2c34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f790510 ___forwarding___ + 1456
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f78fed8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TestApp                           0x000000010006e5c4 __52-[DataManager loadPocketData:pagination:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 356
    6   TestApp                           0x0000000100041c52 __51-[DataManager loadNetworkCustomRequest:completion:]_block_invoke + 162
    7   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff2e7297bf __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
    8   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff2e729021 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 147
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff3185bab3 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff3185b915 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff31859dc2 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100432f1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100446a14 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 576
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100432f1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100446a14 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 576
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001004467b4 dispatch_block_perform + 109
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff31855dd0 __NSOQSchedule_f + 342
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100432f1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001004475be _dispatch_continuation_pop + 940
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010043e5af _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 738
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100434d77 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 723
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100434a50 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 116
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001004af1d2 _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001004aec55 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: `list.count` should returns 0 if it's empty. Also, instead of doing `[object allKeys]`, you could do `for (NSString *aKey in list){ NSDictionary *subDict = list[aKey];}` Also `[object allKeys]` shouldn't crash. Maybe giving your code and the error message in console could help.

Comment: @Larme Normally I do check ```[object count]```, because most JSON structures contain arrays. But in the case of the Pocket API, they use dictionaries only. So you can't check the count of the dictionary itself, because that causes a crash too.

Comment: `NSDictionary *emptyDict = @{}; NSArray *allKeys = [emptyDict allKeys];` None of them create a crash. Could you give the full error message in debugger/console? I'm wondering if there isn't an unrecognized selector sent to instance, with a `NSNull`.

Comment: If the dictionary is not even allocated, than only it may crash on fetching all keys. Otherwise empty dictionary will never crash. It will give a blank list and count = 0. For checking particular key in the dictionary you can enumerate the dictionary. That will also not cause a crash.

Comment: `[__NSArray0 allKeys]` You object is a `NSArray`, not a NSDictionary, that's why it crashes.

Comment: @Larme That doesn't make sense though, because when the ```list``` object is populated, it is of type ```NSDictionary```. I can confirm this, because I checked using ```[object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]```.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff `[object allKeys].count == 0` If the count is 0 there are no keys in the `NSDictionary`.